# Links in SharePoint alert emails not working

Tags: alert

While receiving the SharePoint alert emails, some of links in it are not working. Can anybody give the possible causes

Answer (score 0):

You might not have written the correct url path to the link, or as has happened to me when I wanted to retrieve some information through a link I forgot to transform the link information to a string with `ToString();`